# Basic Programming Error in T24 Design Studio

Tags: jbase

Below is my code.

```
SUBROUTINE HELLO
*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
*
*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
* Modification History :
*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $INSERT I_COMMON
    $INSERT I_EQUATE
*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    CRT "HELLOW WORLD"
END
```

I'm trying to compile above code in T24 Design Studio using TAFJ but it generates below error.

```
17/01/2019 10:50:47 Compiling HELLO...                          ERROR
     Error : (line 19) HELLO, Cannot find Insert 'I_EQUATE'
     Error : (line 12) HELLO.b, No component defined. $PACKAGE is mandatory !
Compilation completed for 1 file(s). 2 errors
```

Need to know how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Please consider ranaming issue to actually contain question

Comment: Issue was fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first error "Cannot find Insert 'I_EQUATE'" means the compiler cannot find the insert file which is usually located inside t24lib. You have to right click on your project and select "Toggle TAFJ project nature", then provide location to t24lib folder with the T24 core libraries (temn.tafj.directory.precompile parameter in TAFJ conf properties).

Second error means that you should follow the TAFJ componentisation framework and you should have a .component and $PACKAGE keyword in routine indicating the package name. You can override this check by putting a "Dunce cup" on the folder where you have the routine.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was able to sort out the issue. But Now I have a different error. 23.01 09:26:52 [ERROR]: Unable to deploy src/xml-t24i/src/SOURCE.BP/ACLIST.enquiry.xml to t24-server. (com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException: The server sent HTTP status code 404: Not Found). Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: Have you setup axis2.war with Temenos components and deployed to Jboss (application server) where your T24 is running? There is a "How-to" document availabe in the Temenos support portal. Axis2.war is the web service component, through wich Design Studio is communicating to the T24 server.

Comment: I don't have axis2.war file

Comment: Axis2 is a .war file that can be downloaded from internet (e.g. https://archive.apache.org/dist/axis/axis2/java/core/1.6.2/). But after that you need to tweek few things in it like add t24-EB_CatalogService-tafj-jws.aar; t24-IF_IntegrationFlowService-tafj-jws.aar and other aar files from the t24lib. The full instruction is too lenghty to write in a comment and is available in Temenos customer support portal FAQs section.

Comment: Can you please send me the link to Temenos customer support portal FAQs section?

Comment: I tried deploying axis2 1_7_9 in WebSphere 9 but got below errors; com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[AxisServlet]: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.axiom.om.OMAbstractFactory (initialization failure)

Comment: and this error com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0014E: Uncaught service() exception root cause /axis2-web/HappyAxis.jsp: com.ibm.websphere.servlet.error.ServletErrorReport: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.axiom.om.OMAbstractFactory &#40;initialization failure&#41;

Comment: You need to access the customer or partner support portal to get to the link, unfortunately. I have not tried deploying axis2.war on WebSpere, only in JBoss. Create new question in stackowerflow - I will try to post the instructions under it.